# Configure wrapping of QTextEdit to add indent

Tags: c++, qt, word-wrap, qtextedit

By default `QTextEdit` wraps long string and displays part of string starting at the beginning of new line. Is it possible to configure the widget so it displays wrapped text after a tabulation in new line?

Comment: Sounds very specific - may be easier to transform the text (e.g. 1. check number of chars in first line, 2. insert tab, 3. check remainder of signs, 4. insert tab, so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using these functions

```
void QTextBlockFormat::setIndent ( int indentation )
void QTextCursor::setBlockFormat ( const QTextBlockFormat & format )
```